# How to append records in a loop?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to append the output of the below loop one below the other, but in output file i get only the result of 'abc3'

Find the script below, Please let me know the change, thanks in advance.

```
for i in abc1 abc2 abc3
do
SELECT_QUERY_1="select substring('$i',4,len('$i')-7) as Table_Name,COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = '$i'  and ORDINAL_POSITION <= (select max(ORDINAL_POSITION)-4 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = '$i')"

echo -e `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S server_name -U username -P user -d db -Q "$SELECT_QUERY_1"  -o "out.txt"`
sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i out.txt

mv out.txt /home/results/out.txt

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line 
`mv out.txt /home/results/out.txt`

to

`cat out.txt >> /home/results/out.txt`

to get all the three results in one file. Because with the `mv` command, the file is overwritten every time. That`s why you only get the last result.

If you do not want to keep the old data in that file, just need to

`rm /home/results/out.txt`

at the begining of the script

Comment: Thank you, but every time i run the script the file must be overwritten, I dont want the old data in there.

Comment: @Venkat In that case you just need to `rm /home/results/result.txt` at the begining of the script

Comment: Thank you @juan for your response.

Comment: In the above same query, I am getting trailing white space for all the column outputs. I dont want any trailing space for any columns. How do I control this?

Comment: @Venkat, I think you should start a new question. Because is a different topic and this one is very related to sqlcmd. Possibly with some arguments would be fixed. Nevertheless, the answer for the original question was a GNU/Linux console commands solution only.

Comment: Anyway, if you post the string of the solution, I could try something to remove the trailing spaces with GNU commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd ... -o "out.txt"`
```

Here, you're using command substitution to catch the output of `sqlcmd`, and then printing it again with echo. This is seldom useful, you could probably just run `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd ... -o "out.txt"` without the command substitution or `echo`. <sub>(There's is a small difference though, unquoted command substitution+echo transforms all whitespace to single spaces.)</sub>

Now, assuming what you want is to concatenate all the outputs of all invocations of `sqlcmd` to a single file, you could use an appending output (`>>`) to direct the result directly to the final file.

If `sqlcmd` outputs normally to stdout, you could just do:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S server_name -U username -P user \
   -d db -Q "$SELECT_QUERY_1" | sed "s/^[ \t]*//" >> /home/results/out.txt
```

If it doesn't support that, you can use `/dev/stdout` as the output file:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S server_name -U username -P user \
   -d db -Q "$SELECT_QUERY_1" -o /dev/stdout | sed "s/^[ \t]*//" >> /home/results/out.txt
```